# Laravel 5.3 notifications message customize

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-notification

I would like to customize this notification email message:

[image]

but i can't find where to change the parts marked with red color on my screenshot.

The "Regards" and the message at the bottom.

Comment: I have found the template for this email but it seems to me this cannot be changed.....it is hardcoded in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php` maybe if i could copy it and edit it...but where do i specify that i want to use my NEW template?

Comment: I have found the solution https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#customizing-the-templates you need to publish the template and then you can edit it how you want it to. If someone wants free points then make an answer for this....

Comment: Solved along time ago

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following command in terminal

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

and edit the blade template in

```
/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php
```

Comment: I was skeptical about this one at first but it's also mentioned in the official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#mail-notifications